# Can I call setHasOptionsMenu() from Fragment Constructor?

Tags: android, fragment, optionmenu

Calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` from constructor, which is obviously called even before `onCreate()`, works perfectly! Can I do that? What will be problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` from the constructor.

Comment: Won't there be any problems, like setting something before onCreate?

Comment: I can't see why there would be any problems after looking at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java).

Answer (score 2):

Check here [fragment - Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

> **Applications should generally not implement a constructor**. The first
>   place application code can run where the fragment is ready to be used
>   is in onAttach(Activity), the point where the fragment is actually
>   associated with its activity. Some applications may also want to
>   implement onInflate(Activity, AttributeSet, Bundle) to retrieve
>   attributes from a layout resource, though should take care here
>   because this happens for the fragment is attached to its activity.

You may want to use another lifecycle event for this.

[image]